# How do I create an 'install' package for a Qt application?

Tags: linux, qt, package, qmake

Generally to install a package on a linux-based operating system you use

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

How does this work? And how do I create a package that can be installed this way?

My application uses the Qt framework and I think I'm aiming for something like "MyPackage.tar.gz"

Answer (score 3):

You can create a debian package from your projects. As I understood you want to create a package intended for distibution so I would suggest creating a debian package from your project. [Here](http://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging) is an introduction for Debian Packaging system. In the article they at some point describe how to create a "rules" file which is at the core of the build process. Here is a sample of it that I typically use for my Qt/KDE projects:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
#export DH_VERBOSE=1
# This is the debhelper compatability version to use.

#export DH_COMPAT=3
DESTDIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/project
TR_DIR=$(CURDIR)/debian/project/usr/share/qt4/translations

configure:
        qmake project.pro

clean:
        dh_testdir
        dh_testroot
        dh_clean

build:  configure
        dh_testdir
        lrelease translations/project_en.ts
        $(MAKE)

install: build
        mkdir -p $(TR_DIR)
        cp translations/project_en.qm $(TR_DIR)
        $(MAKE) INSTALL_ROOT=$(CURDIR)/debian/project install
        dh_installdirs

binary-arch: build install
         dh_testdir
         dh_testroot
         dh_installmenu
         dh_link
         dh_strip
         dh_compress
         dh_fixperms
         dh_installdeb
         dh_shlibdeps
         dh_gencontrol
         dh_md5sums
         dh_builddeb
```

This is normally sufficent for small projects.

Answer (score 2):

`configure` is usually part of GNU build system (autotools), which is not in use in a typical Qt project. `qmake` is used instead for build file generation and it internally handles most of the tasks `configure` does for non-qt projects.

The typical build install process for a Qt application is

```
qmake
make 
make install
```

You could create a simple ./configure script that calls qmake if you need the command names to be identical. You can also use autotools with Qt if you need it, see e.g. [Qt Creator Instructions For Autotools](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-projects-autotools.html)

Answer (score 0):

Qt is often used with CMake, which I highly recommend. One notable point is that it likes out-of-source-builds.

Your configure script could be

```
#!/bin/bash
(mkdir build; cd build; ccmake ..)
```

and the makefile could be

```
#!/bin/bash
(cd build; make)
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of debhelper support qmake.  A *rules* file like,

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
        dh $@ --buildsystem=qmake
```

Is all that is needed.  You need,

```
bar.file = foo
bar.path = install/dir

INSTALLS += bar
```

Inside your projects 'pro' or qmake file.  qmake will create install targets and the perl file */usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Buildsystem/qmake.pm* will get called and parse the qmake file.  You need to create 'debian/' files, *changelog*, *compat*, *control*, *copyright* as well the *rules* file.